# How to get all U.S. census blocks within a state

Tags: programming, census

Is there an easy way to download the set of census blocks (12-digit FIPS codes) for a given state?  I've tried using R packages [tigris](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tigris/index.html) and [acs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/acs/index.html) to no avail.  (Well, tigris works but it gives me the shape data for block which is major overkill since I only want to know *what* blocks are defined for each state.)

Comment: This is a pretty important thing to mention. Census Blocks are 15-Digits, and Census Block Groups are 12-Digits. Estimates from the ACS Summary Files can be drilled-down to the Census Block Group levels; On the other hand, Demographic information are only available at the Census Block level for the LEHD and Decennial Census.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a R-specific answer, but you can download a flat .csv for any given state at the FCC's website: https://www.fcc.gov/general/census-blocks-state

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [NHGIS](https://data2.nhgis.org/main). You can download census block data and shapefiles for multiple years.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only interested in administrative boundaries of Census Blocks, there are 3 options to download Census Block shapefiles from the Census Bureau's pages ([Option 1](https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2015/TABBLOCK/), [Option 2](ftp://ftp.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2015/TABBLOCK/), [Option 3](ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2015/TABBLOCK)). Option 1 is their www2 version which is easier to navigate in a web browser, and option 2/3 are choices that can be used through an FTP program such as FileZilla.

I'll give a brief in description of the file names:

`tl_YYYY_SS_tabblockDD.zip`

The YYYY stands for the year in which the boundaries apply. The SS is the 2-Digit FIPS code for the state in which the Census Blocks are located. The DD stands for the decade in which the Census Block geographical boundaries were created/edited. Finally, tabblock stands for tabulated block.